# Orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory

If we know that $Π_{M}$ is an orthogonal projection on the linear $span(e_{1},e_{2},...,e_{M})$ and we also have arbitrary $r\in(0,1)$ and there exist a natural number M and a positive k , such that

$A_{M,k}:=x\in H :\left | Π_{M}x \right |\leq k$

$C_{M,r}:=x\in H :\left | x-Π_{M}x \right |\leq r$

Also we have points $a_{1},...,a_{l}$ in $B(0,k)\cap H_{M}$ such that

$\bigcup_{i=1}^{l}B(a_{i},r)\supset B(0,k)\cap H_{M}$

and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{l}B(a_{i},2r)\supset A_{M,k}\cap C_{M,r}$

My problem is that I can't truly understand why these set inequalites hold ??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: the $\epsilon$ what purpose has?

Comment: What are $H$ and $H_M$ ? Why do you mention  $ \epsilon$ ?

Comment: H is a Hilbert space , and $H_{M}$ is a subspace in H generated by $e_{1},...,e_{M}$. Don't mind $\epsilon$ , I wrote by mistake.

Comment: Alright. You should edit your question to correct those things. Plus, it is really not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "why this set inequalities hold ?"

Comment: why $\bigcup_{i=1}^{l}B(a_{i},r)\supset B(0,k)\cap H_{M}$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{l}B(a_{i},2r)\supset A_{M,k}\cap C_{M,r}$ hold